# Three.js draw dynamic line between nearest vertices of two models

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two models loaded in a scene using OBJloader and the Three.JS library. Some of the models are billboarded by use of `model.setRotationFromQuaternion( camera.quaternion );`

My goal is to draw lines from a vertex on a billboard to a vertex on the corresponding model - it should be drawn between the nearest points on the two models when the scene is first loaded. The models rotate freely so the lines will need to change as it rotates, staying connected to the same initial verticies.

Think of it like the billboard is a label and the line is connected between the label and somewhere on the rotating model.

How can I achieve this?

Below is a snippet of my code - the issue is that the position of all the models is 0,0,0 so I need to know how to get the location of a vertex on both the label and model and connect the two.

```
 addLabelLines(){
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();    

    for ( var i = 0; i < this.labels.length; i ++ ) { 
        var currentLabel = this.labels[i];
        var modelMatchingLabel;
        //find matching model
        for(var j = 0; j < this.models.length; j++){
          if(currentLabel.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.models[j].name) >= 0){
            modelMatchingLabel = this.models[j];
          }
        }

        if(!modelMatchingLabel){
          console.warn("no model matching label "+currentLabel.name);
          return;
        }
        else{
          console.log('found model '+modelMatchingLabel.name +" matches label "+currentLabel.name);

          geometry.vertices.push( currentLabel.position );
          geometry.vertices.push( modelMatchingLabel.position );
        }        
    }


    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x800080 } );

    line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material, THREE.LineSegments );

    scene.add( line );
  }
```

Comment: May I know what's your nearest vertex mean? some intersections of the line connect two models' center? or, the vertices of the mesh?

Comment: Verticies of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

To get the closest point to be able to draw a line requires your typical "nearest neighbor" algorithms. Take a look at this example, as it'll provide you a very efficient way for achieving what you're looking for

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_nearestneighbour.html